# Is there a Java equivalent to Actionscript's 3.0 Event dispatching? Or, how do I effectively communicate between unrelated class instances?

Tags: java, android, class

I'm starting out in Android development and this has been bugging me a little.

If class A creates an instance of class B and class C, what is the easiest way to communicate between B and C?

In Actionscript 3, I could dispatch an event and have a listener pick it up and act on it but I cannot see something like that in Java. Of course there is the option of passing a reference of B and C into the other from class A but when the path isn't this simple it becomes very hard to follow.

What is the best way to accomplish this in Java/Android?

Answer (score 1):

For Android, I think the best way is to use the Intent api: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Regards,
Deluan.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. Intents (from my understanding at the moment) are for big notification type events that the app needs to react to, not really for a regular call, from a running Thread for example. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I'm starting programming for the Android plataform now, but the documentation says Intents are a messaging facility for communication  between components in the same or different applications. Anyway, it can be an overkill for what you may need. What about the Observer pattern: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=156 ?